# How can we find device token in android emulator for Google Cloud Messaging

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I am trying to implement google cloud messaging by using emulator. but in server side device token is needed. how can i get this token. how can i get the variable "device"

```
import com.google.android.gcm.server.*;

Sender sender = new Sender(myApiKey);
Message message = new Message.Builder().build();
MulticastResult result = sender.send(message, devices, 5);
```

Comment: To whom Google server or your app server?

Comment: actually i am try to use emulator. I would like to know the variable "device " in the above code.

Comment: If you are looking for Device ID the see my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the device ID like this

```
import android.provider.Settings.Secure;
String android_id=Secure.getString(getContext().getContentResolver(),Secure.ANDROID_ID);
```

Answer (score 1):

It register app with GCM. In return it will give an alpha numeric string which will sent to our server for notification. For getting GCM id for your project follow [developer page] : http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/gs.html

```
 public String registerGCM(Context context)
 {
        String TAG = "GCM Already register";
        String SENDER_ID =<Your Gcm ID>;

        GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(context);
        GCMRegistrar.checkManifest(context);

        String gcmRegId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(context);
        System.out.println("GCM Reg id is ======>"+gcmRegId);

        if (gcmRegId.equals("")) 
        {
          GCMRegistrar.register(context, SENDER_ID);
          System.out.println("GCM Reg id is ======>blank");
          String gcmregID = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(context);
          System.out.println("GCM Reg id is ======>"+gcmregID);
          return gcmregID;
        } 
        else 
        {
          Log.v(TAG, "Already registered");
        }
        return gcmRegId;
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

get device id by

```
import android.provider.Settings.Secure;
String android_id=Secure.getString(getContext().getContentResolver(),Secure.ANDROID_ID);
```

Comment: Could you elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?