# How GCM detects various devices with same app

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I am working on an android app and wants to use `GCM`. I have read about GCM from various blogs but i am not getting how GCM detects different devices. I know there is `registration id returned by the GCM server but we are sending project number as sender's id , then how GCM detects various android devices with that app`. Is there any MAC or IMEI number goes along with the sender's id or what?

Any suggestion would be helpful......

Answer (score 0):

as i know That might be Depend on `Secure.ANDROID_ID` , your `Application Packages` and your `GCM` Project Number,

Because i used same `Project Number` for 2 apps running on the Same Devices but `GCM TOKEN` was different for both applications, so it might also depends on the `Package` of you `Android Application`

More Ref : Please check these links

[What is difference between android device id and device token?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17609211/what-is-difference-between-android-device-id-and-device-token)

[How can we find device token in android emulator for Google Cloud Messaging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13580937/how-can-we-find-device-token-in-android-emulator-for-google-cloud-messaging)

Hope it's helpful...